Outer Measure in terms of disjoint elements
I have a question about outer measures. My book defines an outer measure by
$\mu(E)=\inf\{\sum m(A_n) : A_n\in\mathcal{R}, E⊂\bigcup A_n\}$
where $\mathcal{R}$ is a ring and $m$ a measure on it. Now my book claims that the sets $A_n$ could assumed to be disjoint - but I don’t see why.
I had the idea to write any sequence $A_n\in\mathcal{R}$ in terms of disjoint elements by defining
$A_1:=S_1$ and $A_n:=S_n\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i$
then $\bigcup A_k = \bigcup S_k$ and the $A_k$ are disjoint if I didn’t make a mistake. But the corresponding sums are different.
Can you help me please, how I can see that we can assume the disjointness?

You have a bit of swappity-swap between what's $A_n$ and what's $S_n$. If we agree to call $S_n$ the generic covering of $E$ and $A_n$ the disjoint one, then $\forall n, A_n\subseteq S_n$, therefore $\sum_n m(A_n)\le \sum_n m(S_n)$ and the highest lower bound of the sums is not affected.

Great! Thank you :-)
